# ng-init not working on initializing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started to learn angular.js but `ng-init` is not working in my code. I searched through internet but wasn't able to find any answer.

Here is my code thanks in advance !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ngClassifieds</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app = "ngClassifieds" ng-init="message='hello, World!'">
        <h1 ng-model="message">{{ message }}</h1>
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show app.js file, any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code below in your app.js

```
var ngClassifieds=angular.module("ngClassifieds",[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with script loading

```
<head>
    <title>ngClassifieds</title>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

add your scripts in header tag

Answer (score 0):

Html Code

```
  <body ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main" ng-init="data='welcome'">  
 {{data}}
  </body>
```

Script Code

```
      var app = angular.module('main', []);
       app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

        });
```